# Field Validation in Repeater Control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox, repeater, customvalidator

I have a question related to asp.net and vb.net. I have a repeater control that I bind some data to and allow users to update/change fields within certain text boxes. I added a validation control to trigger when the user doesn't enter a valid date or the text "TBD". On submit, I want to go through and highlight each field where its corresponding validator is not valid. This is my current code, but I am lost as to how to find the text box control.

```
Sub ValidateDateField(ByVal sender As Object, _
                      ByVal args As ServerValidateEventArgs)
    'validate against three conditions - date, "TBD", and "N/A"
    Dim dtValue = args.Value
    If dtValue.ToUpper = "TBD" Or dtValue.ToUpper = "N/A" Then
        args.IsValid = True
    ElseIf IsDate(dtValue) Then
        args.IsValid = True
    Else
        args.IsValid = False

        Dim cont As WebControl = DirectCast(Page.FindControl(args.ToString), WebControl)

        cont.BackColor = Drawing.Color.White

        util.Client_Alert("Please Update Highlighted Fields")

    End If
End Sub
```

I am completely lost as to how to get cont = textbox1row1 of my repeater control. Please advise. All examples I have seen so far directly state the control as in text1.BackColor =

Comment: So I got this to work, may be a clumsy way to do it, but I can't post for validation. I have to wait for 8 hours. Will repost when I am allowed.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the answer. Sorry for the question. Don't know why I didn't think about it sooner. I found the naming container of the my custom val and then found the control based on its name in the repeater. in vb.net it was something like this:

```
Sub ValidateDateField(ByVal sender As Object, _
                      ByVal args As ServerValidateEventArgs)

    'args holds value. validate against three conditions - date, "TBD", and "N/A"
    Dim dtValue = args.Value

    Dim cont As CustomValidator = sender
    Dim myNC As Control = cont.NamingContainer    
    Dim strControl As String

    strControl = cont.ControlToValidate

    Dim txtbox As TextBox = _
      DirectCast(myNC.FindControl(cont.ControlToValidate), TextBox)

    If dtValue.ToUpper = "TBD" Or dtValue.ToUpper = "N/A" Or IsDate(dtValue) Then
        args.IsValid = True
        txtbox.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Empty
    Else
        args.IsValid = False

        txtbox.BackColor = Drawing.Color.White

    End If

End Sub
```